# Determine if a SWF (Flash) object loaded completely using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to use JavaScript to detect whether a .swf file has loaded completely within a web page?

Assume that the .swf file is pulled from a 3rd-party website and we don't have access to its source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the loading of the SWF is done by the Flash Player, not the browser, and the Flash Player doesn't expose any javascript API.

Answer (score 3):

You can call movie.PercentLoaded() from Javascript.

Other useful functions are listed here:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html